# Selecting/Querying a JSON for a variable Object in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, object

I have a JSON in a SQL database that formerly looked like that:

```
{   "result": {
        "topResult": {
            "score": 1}
    }
}
```

For a bigger query, I want to select the score in this object structure via SQL, which I did with this operator (or JSON_extract):

```
object->>'$.result.topResult.score' AS 'Score'
```

The problem that I now have is that the name "topResult" is variable/changing, so this query doesn't work anymore (or at least only case specific)

How can I make my Select statement a bit more generic to still output me the score regardless of the object before?

My ideas:

- I can derive the name of the object from somewhere else in the JSON
  --> could I reuse it as an alias, a variable or a concatenation to fill in the variable?
- Is there a possibility to "skip" or index a JSON object?
- Can ignore the path before and just look for a specific object like "score"?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.val,
                      '$.result.*' COLUMNS (score INT PATH '$.score')) jsontable;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46fbf88c6b4ce01b3cb5e0040c86451b